# How can I replace a value already present in the database?

Tags: 7, database

Is there a way for `db_insert()` to overwrite existing entries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @kiamlaluno mentioned `db_insert()` inserts a new row in the table. You can use `db_update()`, to update the row if it already exists. You can use [db_merge()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21database%21database.inc/function/db_merge/7), to combine both of them.
See the example (taken from [the documentation](https://drupal.org/node/310085)):

```
db_merge('example')
  ->key(array('name' => $name))
  ->fields(array(
      'field1' => $value1,
      'field2' => $value2,
    ))
  ->execute();
```

> In the above example, we instruct the query to operate on the "example" table. We then specify one key field, 'name', with a value of $name. We then specify an array of values to set.
>
> If a row already exists in which the field "name" has the value $name, then fields field1 and field2 will be set to the corresponding values in that existing row. If such a row does not exist, one will be created in which name has the value $name, field1 has the value $value1, and field2 has the value $value2. Thus at the end of the query, the end result is the same regardless of whether or not the row already existed.

Comment: db_merge acts like an if statement for queries? It runs an update query if a row with that primary key value exists and an insert query if it doesn't? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: @jsalita Stop on. It does exactly that.

Answer (score 2):

`db_insert()` inserts a new row in the table; if you need to update an existing row, you need to use [db_update()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_update/7).

```
db_update('system')
  ->fields(array('status' => 0))
  ->condition('type', 'module')
  ->condition('name', $module)
  ->execute();
```

The fields passed to `fields()` are the ones that need to be updated.